# Uploading repositories to BitBucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Just wanted to check something with you regarding Mercurial and BitBucket, since I'm not sure if it's something on my side or has something changed in their web interface (I almost never look at it - just remember the URL's and that's it).

I recently created a new account on BitBucket, and a new repo (well, several of them, but let's go with now for this example). It gave me a link in the form of

```
https://..../myusername/name_of_repo
```

then I went to my local repo and did

```
hg push https://... (same thing as above)
```

Now when I go to `https://bitbucket.org/myusername` I can see all my repositories on the right side, and *recent history* activity, but when I click on the big *Repositories* button on the top, it says *Repositories not found.* It's kinda annoying because I don't feel writing down the bitbucket URL/myusername every time I wish to check my repos.

So, I'm interested - is that an error on my side (me doing something wrong) or ... ?

*This could probably be thought of offtopic here as it doesn't deal with software in general, but it is so programming related that I really don't think it belongs on webapps. Besides programmers are the only ones who will know what I'm talking about here.*

Comment: When I press on `Repositories` button in the top menu I'm forwarded to `https://bitbucket.org/repo/mine` and I see all my repos

Comment: @zerkms - I expected the same. Only I see none (message "No repos found" or something of a kind). However, when I go to bit_bucket_address/myusername/ I see them all.

Comment: @zerkms - In any case, thank you. That's what I wanted to verify. Btw, do you have any idea where to report/get feedback on this issue?

Comment: @zerkms - Disregard my last comments. I just checked the account again and now the repositories are there - it must've been that they need time to show up, and I was impatient or something (bb had a maintenance recently). If you want put that comment of yours and I'll accept it; otherwise I'll just delete this whole story.

Comment: there is a link in the bottom `Report a Bug to Bitbucket`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like the issue was caused by some sort of cache ;-)

Comment: Okey, that last one made me laugh :)))